# Implications of expected value of a regression given the regressor matrix

Tags: multiple-regression, econometrics, expected-value, matrix

As I am currently preparing for a econometrics exam I struggle to recall the correct theoretical explanation for the connection between the expected value of a estimator given the matrix of all estimators. Particularly, in need help in the explanation for the correct answer which is marked in yellow in he picture below.

Thank you everyone!

[image]

Comment: Hi Fabio, welcome to the site! I don't see a picture.

Comment: Hi John, my apologies, I’ve updated my post with a picture of the question I had trouble understanding.